# Using Laptop to serve as monitor, keyboard and mouse to another PC

Tags: usb, laptop, remote-control

I have a laptop for my regular use which is compact and for regular day to day work.

I need a much powerful PC so I buy/ assemble one. But I dont want to buy peripherals like Monitor, Keyboard and Mouse. I want to leverage my laptop for this.

I have the right software/drivers installed on my laptop.
On PC i connect usb cables as if I am connecting a USB monitor, Keyboard, Mouse.

The other end i connect to my Laptop's USB port or any other port. May be there is a hub in between which mux the three usb cables to one.

I run the right application on my Laptop
Boot my new PC and this application on my laptop shows what a monitor would show i.e. the bootup sequence
When I type anything on the application on my laptop it is registered on the PC. Thus

I get the PC's bios with my laptop and configure it.

I install the OS on the PC but interfacing with my this application on my laptop.
Once OS is installed i can control the GUI of my PC from my laptop. Or keep it running but when I need to control it i can use this application and USB cables.

This idea is like running a VM on my laptop which I do. Only thing is this VM application controls a hardware PC instead.

Additionally a device which stands in between like for e.g. a dock which is connected to via usb/thunderbolt on one side but to laptop via ethernet on another and instead of connecting to monitor/keyboard/mouse it actually streams these to the laptop where the application interprets the data and shows it in its screen and takes inputs from keyboard/trackpad and pass them back to the doc which will send them back to the pc.

Comment: Are both computers going to run Linux/Unix, or at least the newer one?

Comment: The PC can run any OS
The Laptop can run any OS for which we develop the software. Since writing drivers on linux is relatively easy because of open source and community support I think Linux can be preferred.